# Can't connect to 4D server via Wakanda 4D Mobile

Tags: wakanda, 4d-database

I have a v16 database with 4D Mobile enabled:
[image]

I have the 4D Mobile License:
[image]

The webserver is running and the "Total HTTP Hits" counter increments during failed 4D Mobile connection attempts:
[image]

I can connect to other V16 Databases via 4D Mobile running on that machine.

I am using a valid username and password:
[image]

I have a valid license for Wakanda 2.6 in my ~/Documents/Wakanda/license/license.key (which must be true since this Wakanda can connect to the other V16 databases)

What am I missing, or what can I do to learn about why the error is happening? I have checked the 4D Server web log (CLF), and the Wakanda Solution Log, which says:

`2018-10-30 13:24:08 [wakanda.PlannerTool4] INFO - Users and groups directory opened
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.backend.dbmg] ERROR - [1595] The "Inventory" remote datastore class cannot be created locally, task #775
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.backend.dbmg] ERROR - [1024] Cannot open structure of database backend, task #775
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.backend.iasv] ERROR - [1035] Cannot open the datastore, task #775
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.backend] WARN - "backend" project opened with errors
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.iasv] ERROR - [1013] Cannot open 'backend' project, task #775
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4.backend] INFO - "backend" project closed
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4] WARN - "PlannerTool4" solution opened with errors
2018-10-30 13:24:09 [wakanda.PlannerTool4] INFO - "PlannerTool4" solution closed`

Edit: the Database methods On Web Authentication, On Web Connection, and On 4D Mobile Authentication are all nonexistant. It's not that they're blank, which I know can be an issue. They have not been created.

Comment: Sorry for the simple question :) do you have some table with flag "Expose with 4D Mobile Service" on? By default they should be exposed,

Comment: Are the two machines on the same subnet?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to create a new remote model rather than edit an existing remote model config. The error message I got when editing the existing model config was "Connection failed. Please check the Server's connection settings", which was of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new remote model rather than edit an existing remote model config. The error message I got when editing the existing model config was "Connection failed. Please check the Server's connection settings"